# Optimal way to aproach the logic

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, hash

I have 2 array list of files (consider large number of files in it (1k -5k))

This is created on fly when new files are added.

```
addedfiles=['temp.java', 'TEMP.java', 'DENT.java', 'Seal.java']
note: This files like temp.java and TEMP.java are same, added in case-sensitive way and are duplicates.
```

These files are all-ready present in system

```
ExistingFiles=['dent.java', 'temp1.java','comp.java']
note: They are distinct and unique from each other.
```

I am trying come with optimal logic to add distinct unique files from **addedfiles** to **ExistingFiles**.

So, in above only Seal.java file will be added in ExistingFiles as it is distinctly unqiue in addedfiles.

My logic:

```
    1. create a hashmap from addedfiles like [name:count]
        {temp.java:2, DENT.java:1,Seal.java:1}
    2. creating nonduplicate array =[DENT.java,Seal.java]
    3. comparing ExistingFiles and nonduplicate array using sort and binarysearch 
       if value is >=0 add value from nonduplicate to ExistingFiles.
```

Is there any better way to do this **by using union or intersection** or ***threads*** thanks:)

Comment: Are you comparing file **names** or file **content**?

Comment: How frequently are you doing the comparison?  Once a second, once an hour, once a month?

Comment: @StephenC filenames. Comparison happens whenever new set of files are added.

Comment: Do you need to retain the case of the filenames in `ExistingFiles`? If not, then I recommend using a `HashSet` for `ExistingFiles` and only store lower-cased names in it. Then to check whether a filename already exists in the set, convert that filename `toLowerCase()` first and pass it to `ExistingFiles.contains()`.

Comment: @bui So if the files are repeating in the addedfiles they are not added in the existing files they are removed

Comment: Suspiciously similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71936354/optimization-of-algorithm-for-distinctive-array

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to retain the case of the filenames, I would store lower-cased existing files' name in a `Set`, says `existingFiles`, and do it as follows

```
Set<String> newFiles = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> dupFiles = new HashSet<>();
for (String filename : addedFiles) {
    filename = filename.toLowerCase();
    if (existingFiles.contains(filename)) { continue; }
    if (newFiles.contains(filename)) { 
        dupFiles.add(filename); 
    } else {
        newFiles.add(filename);
    }
}
newFiles.removeAll(dupFiles);
existingFiles.addAll(newFiles);
```

This solution is a little memory-heavy, but if speed is critical, it works well.